# Are forbidden relations forbidden to the passive non-jew?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, noachide-laws

(Rambam [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.9.5), [HebrewBooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14994), [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/1188354/))
A non-jewish man cannot have relations with:

1. (a woman who was) his father's wife
2. his mother
3. a (another) man's wife
4. his maternal sister
5. a man
6. an animal

Does this include the passive non-jewish party?
Is the woman in these cases (1-4, 6) also subjected to death?
How about the passive man (by case number 5)?

Comment: 1. His father's **present** wife. Gentiles do not keep relations.

Comment: there seems to be evidence that she does have at least the 6 mitzvot since a woman is not listed here https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.10.2  (end)

Comment: Seems that the first and last question are one to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Both are liable if they are consenting adults.
2. The same prohibitions regarding to man also applies to woman . The reason is that all these references are derived from a verse which the talmud [Sanhedrin 57b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.57b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) interprets as referring to both, man and woman.

Source: Sefer Sheva Mitsvos Hashem, vol II under the laws of giluy arayos.

Comment: does this include a woman with an animal?

Comment: @hazoriz: Yes, it does include.