# Is a non-Jew forbidden to his father's ex-wife?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage, arayot

A Jewish man and his father's wife are forbidden to each other forever, even after his father dies or divorces her. ([Issurei Biah 2:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960648/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Two.htm))

A non-Jewish man and his father's wife are forbidden to each other, even after his father dies. ([Melachim uMilchamot 9:5-6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9.5?lang=bi))

Does the prohibition continue if she and his father divorce?

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90727/are-forbidden-relations-forbidden-to-the-passive-non-jew) says yes, but a comment says no. One possible difficulty is that divorce for non-Jews is a rather [informal affair](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9.8?lang=bi) and it might be harder to tell when she becomes permitted.

Comment: It seems she is forbidden; unless one of them convert(maybe even in his lifetime). Is a divorce less severe than death, that she should be permitted?

Comment: R' Weiner's _Sefer 7 Mitzvot_ answers yes, quoting R' Shteif's _Sefer Mitzvot Hashem_ p. 392. Need to find that passage and make it an answer.